# Image Segmentation From Edge Detection

Tags: java, android, edge-detection, image-segmentation

How can i apply segmentation technique through edge detection in android? what i want to do is run edge detection on a picture and extract some part of choice from the picture. Could be a bitmap or a jpeg. Is this possible in android? is there a working example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case isn't very descriptive, so I only give a general answer. Maybe you can go a bit deeper into detail of your problem you want to solve.

If you aren't afraid of using modern C++ techniques, then I highly recommend [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).
It has a lot of features regarding image segmentation and edge detection.
For example the [Canny Edge Detector](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) is fully implemented in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenCV4Android.
And then you should create a region of interest (ROI) with the edge detection or you can use findContours.

You can take a look at this tutorial for OpenCV at [link](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp?rev=4079)